# Create a temporal post

Tags: php, functions

I want to create a post dynamically through a function (done that) but I want to know if its possible to make that the created post delete itself after a specific parameter (time, function, etc)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the [cron API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) which you can use to schedule background jobs such as auto-deleting posts.

Comment: ok, I'll check that. Thanks